# Transformation Matrix for cube in 2D

Tags: matrices, transformation

My task is to transform the cube from the left corner to the big cube in the middle:

What I did was:

First i scale the cube:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        4 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 4 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Next i rotate it $45^\circ$:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \cos(45^\circ) & -\sin(45^\circ) & 0 \\
        \sin(45^\circ) & \cos(45^\circ) & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

And last i translate the cube:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 10 \\
        0 & 1 & 7 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

When i  combine this matrices i get my transformation matrix:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        4\cos(45^\circ) & -4\sin(45^\circ) & 40\cos(45^\circ) - 28\sin(45^\circ) \\
        4\sin(45^\circ) & 4\cos(45^\circ) & 40\cos(45^\circ) + 28\sin(45^\circ) \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

But then i tried to apply this matrix to the point $(0,1,1)$ and i got an wrong result:

$$(5.6, 50.9116 ,1)$$

As you can see it should be around:

$$(7.1, 9.9, 1)$$

What did I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Better to tell us how you are going to implement these matrices on each point especially for transform matrix.

Comment: @Arashium I take one point for example (1,1,1) and multiply it with my transformation-matrix!

Comment: oop, translation matrix. is it $x=x+T$ or $x=T\times x$?

Comment: I would say $x = T x X$

Comment: But 
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 10 \\
        0 & 1 & 7 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$ * (1,1,1) = (10,7,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your multiplication.

$$
        T_{total}=\begin{pmatrix}
        4\cos(45^\circ) & -4\sin(45^\circ) & 40\cos(45^\circ) - 28\sin(45^\circ) \\
        4\sin(45^\circ) & 4\cos(45^\circ) & \color{red}{28\cos(45^\circ) + 40\sin(45^\circ)} \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

But, since $sin (45^\circ)$ and $cos (45^\circ)$ have the same value, the problem is not from this point.

The problem is related to the order of the Transforms. In matrix multiplication, you should care about matrix order.

$T1$ is scale transform

$T2$ is rotation transform

$T3$ is translation transform

you computed:

$$X_{new}=(T1 \times T2 \times T3) \times X_{old}$$

while, you need to scale first then rotation then translation:

$$X_{new}=(T3 \times T2 \times T1) \times X_{old}$$

$$T3 \times T2 \times T1=\begin{pmatrix}
        4\cos(45^\circ) & -4\sin(45^\circ) & 10 \\
        4\sin(45^\circ) & 4\cos(45^\circ) & 7 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

$$T1\times T2 \times T3 \times \begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        5.66 \\
        50.91 \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

While

$$T3\times T2 \times T1 \times \begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        7.17 \\
        9.83 \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks Arashium! But I didnt't understand what I should do instead?

Comment: See my update....